# SBT release plugin creates SNAPSHOT jar

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

My jenkins job run the below command , but it's generating SNAPSHOT jar only.

```
sbt 'set isSnapshot := false' 'set releaseIgnoreUntrackedFiles := true' 'release skip-tests with-defaults'
```

Here is my publish.sbt file

```
import sbtrelease._
import sbtrelease.ReleaseStateTransformations._


publishTo := {
  val nexus = "https://repository.xyz.com/content/repositories/"
  if (isSnapshot.value)
    Some("snapshots" at nexus + "snapshots/my_project/")
  else
    Some("releases" at nexus + "releases/my_project/")
}

releaseProcess := Seq[ReleaseStep](
  checkSnapshotDependencies,
  inquireVersions,
  setReleaseVersion,
  commitReleaseVersion,
  tagRelease,
  publishArtifacts,
  setNextVersion,
  commitNextVersion,
  pushChanges
)

releaseIgnoreUntrackedFiles := true
```

Comment: does your application version in your build.sbt end with -SNAPSHOT ?

Comment: yes, but when we release it creates a new stable version from it